# How to stop previous interval in function when new interval started

Tags: javascript, ajax, setinterval

When I call my function, it starts an interval to refresh the chat screen. However when I select a different user (different parameters) the previous interval continues and I am not sure how to stop the previous interval when the new interval begins. I have tried calling clearInterval() from outside the function but I think my syntax must be wrong because it shows the interval as undefined.

Here is my code.

```
function selectrecipient(x,y){
  clearInterval(refint);
  var refint = setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '../includes/chat/msgs.php',
      data: ({ chosenuser : x }), 
      success: function(data){
        document.getElementById('messagehistory').innerHTML = data;
      }
    });

    document.getElementById("recipientid").value = ""+x+"";
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: If you mean that `selectrecipient` is called multiple times, then the scope of `refint` is wrong. Move the variable declaration outside of your function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable `refint` in a outer scope else the value of the variable will be reset on every call to the method. In your case since you have declared it as a local variable in each call to `selectrecipient` a new variable will be used and when `clearInterval` it will have the value `undefined`

```
var refint;

function selectrecipient(x, y) {
    clearInterval(refint);
    refint = setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../includes/chat/msgs.php',
            data: ({
                chosenuser: x
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                document.getElementById('messagehistory').innerHTML = data;
            }
        });

        document.getElementById("recipientid").value = "" + x + "";
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Actually that worked really well. Thankyou! I also had to remove the var declaration before refint inside the function. Once I did that the problem was solved.